# React native Expo twitter authentication

Tags: authentication, react-native, twitter, expo

I want to implement Twitter authentication in an app created with 'create-react-native-app'. I have looked docs of Expo, but I found that Expo supports authentication only with Facebook and google. I'm unable to use Oauth, because I can't link the package. I don't want to detache, want to keep Expo. Is there any way to do what I need? Thanks for attention.

Comment: This may not be possible without implementing your own backend, I found this project on expo's Github https://github.com/expo/expo-twitter-login-example Another one contains Twitter auth code - https://github.com/expo/auth0-example - Or you can use a WebView/AuthSession

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `repo` in official expo examples:

https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-twitter-auth

and to use it >> upload the backend server to any node cloud host like `heroku`. and use the `urls` in the front-end `App.js` to point to the server url.